# Unable to Display PDF file in Browser using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing an issue, in which I am not able to display PDF file in any web browser using MCV.
I am not getting any error but just shows me D�*�PV�B/���S�zi ������������

I am using Bootstrap, Jquery and MVC.
Bellow is sample code to display PDF.

```
    public FileResult OpenDocument(int Id)
    {
        byte[] data = lst.File; // retrieve byte from db.
        string mimeType = "application/pdf";
        if (mimeType != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", data.Length.ToString());
            //Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        }
        return File(data, mimeType);
    }
```

Please help me or Suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks suspect: `return File(mimeType, mimeType);` You are using `mimeType` for both parameters... shouldn't 1 parameter be the file data or path?

Comment: @zgood: Please post that as answer, since it's very much the issue here.

Comment: Hi @Nishant, have you tried my solution? This is how I do it in my application and it definitely works. So if you implement this and still have the same problem then the issue is with how you are storing or retrieving the Byte[] data!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

If you want it to open the pdf in the browser window, just remove the FileDownloadName line.

```
    public ActionResult OpenDocument(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = lst.File; // retrieve byte from db.
            string mimeType = "application/pdf";
            FileContentResult document = new FileContentResult(data, mimeType);
            document.FileDownloadName = "something.pdf";
            return document;
        }
        catch
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example you need to pass `data` to the `File` content result.

```
public ActionResult OpenDocument(int Id)
{
    //Code that uses Id to retrieve 1st variable
    //....
    byte[] data = lst.File; // retrieve byte array from db.
    if(data!=null && data.Length > 0) {
        string mimeType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + Id + ".pdf");
        return File(data, mimeType);
    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: The default disposition is inline. As a result, this has nothing to do with the OP's issue.

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, Thanks for your suggestion but still an issue is persisit, shows me D�*�PV�B/���S�zi ������������ in browser. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: ** after apply your suggestion still pdf shows in browser looks like : ** %PDF-1.3 %���� 12 0 obj <> endobj 31 0 obj <>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<125ED202E41E8B49820680647CDB0267>]/Index[12 31]/Info 11 0 R/Length 93/Prev 54710/Root 13 0 R/Size 43/Type/XRef/W[1 2 1]>>stream h�bbd``b`Z$l��f ��$�8��C !�����-�A�� V?�bՁX�@�k2��L)*L� u�D�~0}�1 endstream endobj startxref 0 %%EOF 42 0 obj <>stream h�b```f``�e`a`�``@�+s<�����,������``�� #A(f`������ƵA��}Oǐ�Cl��hD&,b���NiDc�4�f" �##3 endstream endobj

Comment: Have you taken a look at the others answers. If this isn't working for you then you should take a look at them and see if they work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding issue. Try to add this line in your response

```
 Response.Charset = "utf-8";
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate this is a bit old now, but I recently had the same issue when using either Rotativa / DinkToPDF. 
Turned out the code was fine, but was seeing �s due to me posting the form via ajax.

I disabled ajax form posting and it worked!

Hope this helps